# Modern-C++ reflection library

Tags: library, software-development, c++

I'm interested in using a reflection library with my code, without going into details, I'm interested in understand what's available out there, strengths and weaknesses etc.

So far I've noticed:

- [CAMP](https://github.com/tegesoft/camp) - half-abandoned, no commits for almost a year.
- [Ponder](http://billyquith.github.io/ponder/) - A CAMP fork which seems to be more active.
- [XM](https://github.com/m4nu3lf/eXtendedMirror) - quarter-abandoned, no commits for half a year at the time I'm writing this.
- [CppRefl](http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/reflcpp/) - have not checked it out yet.
- [(non-)Boost.Reflect](http://bytemaster.github.io/boost_reflect/) - A boost-style library which is not part of Boost itself.
- [Boost.Mirror](http://bytemaster.github.io/boost_reflect/) - A boost-style library which is not part of Boost itself.
- [Mirror C++ Reflection Utilities](http://kifri.fri.uniza.sk/~chochlik/mirror-lib/html/) Another Boost'ish-style, but not part of Boost. Seems to have been abandoned in 2011.

I couldn't quite find a comparative review of these, or a recommendation from someone who has experience working with them. So, please recommend (or counter-recommend) one of these, or any other reflection library you know of.

**Notes:**

- I prefer libraries which require C++11 or C++14 (and thus less ugly and convoluted).
- Dependence on Boost is (grudgingly) acceptable, as well as dependence on any other (hopefully non-esoteric) library.

Comment: Its hard to do reflection *inside* C++.  If your willing to step outside the language (this may fail your "nonesoteric" requirement), you can get complete metaprogramming access to every aspect of C++ source code.  See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/257266/c-metaprogramming-with-a-compiler-api-rather-than-with-c-features/257441#257441

Comment: @IraBaxter: I don't care about the source code, only about what the source code represents. And I don't want to transform the source, either, although I suppose some kind of a source transformer _may_ (with a capital M) be relevant.

Comment: Agreed you don't want to manipulate source code *text*.  The point of the tool I mentioned is that it provides programmatic aspect to the code *structure* (as an AST) and (out of the box) to all the facts you might consider asking in a reflection world *as data structures*.  For more exotic questions about the code, they can be implemented as custom analyzers in that framework.  Of course, there's always the question of what do you want to *do* with the answers you get; often it is "modify the behavior of the code", which can be done by source transformation.

Answer (score 1):

There is Antony Polukhin's

## [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get)

now known as “Precise and Flat Reflection”.  He gave a talk about this library at CppCon 2016: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abdeAew3gmQ

Comment: It allows for a _bit_ of reflection. It's a wonderful hack, but doesn't cover what I need.